# Would like to convert my columns into category values under 1 new column in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So let's say I have the table below with the Boys, Girls, and Total columns, and each value is the number of said boys and girls. How would I go about creating a new table with one column: gender, and placing the values of boys and girls into a new column: quantity. So under my new gender column i'll have boys and girls as values instead of having two separate columns for each gender.

| Boys | Girls | Total |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 | 7 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY:

```
df = df[['Boys','Girls']].melt(var_name= 'Gender', value_name= 'Quantity')
```